# Ionic 3 Post Request

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm looking to link my register.html and my register.ts file together for a post request to my back-end. I'm creating a register screen which will send the information to my database (mongoDB/Node)

I started to use [{ngModel}] like in the example below:

```
 <form id="signup-form3">
    <ion-list id="signup-list2">
      <ion-item id="signup-input6">
        <ion-label>
          email
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" placeholder="Email"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

However kept receiving an error: 'Can't bind to '{ngModel}' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'. This was after I put all the necessary imports into my app.module.ts.

In my TS file I'm sending the post request using...

```
register() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    let body = {
      email: "this.email",
      password: "this.password"
    };

    this.http.post('http://localhost:3005/v1/account/register', JSON.stringify(body), {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

Wasn't sure if there was an easier way of going about it or if I'm using ngModel the wrong way.

**Edit**: Fixed the [(ngModel)] typo. Giving me error now that...

"A user with the given username is already registered" - Which I think it's sending "this.email" to the database - althought when I console log it out, it's showing the email. Is this an issue with the JSON.stringify?

**Edit 2** : Getting an error now from my back-end : 'Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues is that it's not `[{ngModel}]`, it's `[(ngModel)]`. That should solve the issue.

**EDIT:**

Remove the `""` from `this.email` and `this.password` on the body, should be something like this:

```
let body = {
  email: this.email,
  password: this.password
};
```

Comment: Had a small typo! Fixed it and still have a reoccuring error with the DB and the post connection

Comment: @cdh429 Edited the answer

Comment: I'm getting this this error when I make the changes...

'ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0' @ChesterLaborde

Comment: Although looking at the database, it did register it. very strange @ChesterLaborde

Comment: @cdh429 I would remove the JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out the issue with the help of @ChesterLaborde

I had to take out .map(res => res.json())

As @ChesterLaborde mentioned to take out the Stringify - I believe it was because I'm already turning it into JSON, and the .map(res => res.json()) was trying to do it again. I believe this was the root of the problem, worked for me at least.

Comment: In this case taking out the .map(res => res.json()) might work, but in the future where the response does matter, you will need to map it to JSON. Also if you found of any help my answer, you should mark it as accpeted

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on this? Also I just marked your answer complete. Thank you for the help! @ChesterLaborde

Comment: Let's say you do a get call to your server, and you'd like to show the response. You would need to map the response the server gave you to a JSON object to work with it